# Different snapshot version of artifacts from one deployment cycle

Tags: java, maven-3

I'm deploying 6 artifacts from an ANT based project. So that they are deployed one after another.

Problem is, that the snapshot version differs for all of them. It just shares the artifact version, the timestamp, but the last number is different.

```
6.1.0-20110331.121641-1
```

The problem that this causes is that I can't create this property:

```
<program.version>6.1.0-20110331.121641-1</program.version>
```

And I have to specify the exact version number for each of those 6 artifact if I want to go back to or test an older snapshot version.

Is there any workaround for this ?

EDITED:  the point is -  I need to use an older version of a snapshot artifacts ... so that as it is now, I would have to manually change versions of all 6 artifacts

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are talking about the SNAPSHOT versions, right?

So you should have `6.1.0-SNAPSHOT-20110331.121641-1`. Right?

So you need to depend on `6.1.0-SNAPSHOT` version, without the timestamp.

Comment: I need to use the older snapshot artifact, SNAPSHOT means the latest one

Comment: I know that snapshots are not meant for that, but sometimes you get into a situation, where you can do something only with the previous version of artifacts, because it doesn't work with those you deployed. You know what I mean? For instance you have a 7th artifact that uses all those 6 artifacts, you deploy them and the 7th one doesn't work with them anymore and you'd like to switch back to the previous version. It is not so common thing but it happens

Comment: I see. Well, I don't have any good solution for this. You probably need to set the versions explicitly for each dependency.